Can the mathematical statements in John Derbyshire's book Bernhard Riemann and the Greatest Unsolved Problem in Mathematics be trusted?
After read this book, I think John Derbyshire's descriptions of math history (Gauss in 1737?? Riemann who obtained the formula by referring to Hadamard's paper in 1892???) seemed to confuse the years, etc.
So what I'm curious about is whether Riemann's mathematical achievements in this book are trustworthy.
+) After checking the original text, it was clear that the translation of the version I was reading was incorrect. Thank you for everyone who found the link to the original file and responded in detail.

Can you provide page numbers?

These are pages 142 and 213. Oh, I forgot to say, but since it is a translated version, the page may not be clear based on the English version. According to this version(version I am reading), it was 142p and 213p.

There is a pdf of the book here http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Fichiers%20Claude/Nombres/Derbyshire%20-%20Prime%20Obsession%20-%20Bernhard%20Riemann%20and%20the%20Greatest%20Unsolved%20Problem%20in%20MathematicsAAA.pdf

The year 1737 occurs twice in the book, on p. 97 and p. 106.
Both dates refer to Euler’s Variae observationes circa
series infinitas published in 1737. Is the date wrong?

I guess the translation of the version of the book I was reading was wrong... Thank you for your checking.

The date 1837 occurs many times, perhaps it is a typographical error in the translation? The second case regarding Riemann "reading" Hadamard also smacks of a mistranslation. I could not find any reference in the English that matches this: "Meanwhile, Riemann's 1859 paper was being scrutinized, and its
arguments tidied up. Hadamard's prize result of 1892 was a great step
forward." is the likely English passage. Notice that this does not refer to Riemann reading Hadamard but undefined people scruitinizing Riemann's paper. In short if anything is untrustworthy here it might be the translation.
